# Check Transaction Termination

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, transactions

Need some ideas to track whether the user is terminating a payment transaction.

Some scenarios in which it may happen is-

1. The user closes his browser during interaction with Bank or Verified by Visa Page
2. The external bank side does not load up due to pop-up blocker or due to network issue.

etc etc

Is there anyway i could be able to keep a track of all this.

Comment: As i look for it, there is away you can detect if a user is closing browser on chrome, safari, or if the user is clicking the back button. Just forgotten how to do it, but there is an answer on SO for that

Answer (score 1):

1. Largely depends on protocol being used. For example, Atmosphere allows server-side to get notifications when browser window is closed: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/onDisconnect-tricks
   Fallback method, when you have no notifications from your messaging library, is to employ heartbeats: if your server had no heartbeat for last N seconds, consider transaction being cancelled and de-allocate server-side resources.
2. Heartbeats will help you here.

Comment: I keep track of transaction based on session cookies.... When the transaction is passed to Bank the control is passed to customer and all server resources are deallocated until and unless we get a response from the customer with the session id. Then based on tht identification we proceed ahead. So based on this if there is no response in tht step we are losing the transaction

Comment: @anupsahu if this is pure request-response, w/o keep-alive connection, you can consider transaction cancelled if some timeout elapsed and there was no response from client.